# Riot Api - Rest call for items and images

Tags: json, rest

I am started to work with the riot api and so far I love riot for offering this possibility.
Can someone please help me how to write a rest call to get
- not the item parts but only the full item (like athene's unholy grail and not fiendish codex and chalice of harmony) 
- the images for the items 
- the item name
Here ist the website: https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/#static-data-v3
Or do I have to get all items and have to filter them by myself? Highly appreciate your help!
Thanks and see you on summoner's rift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to query all items and filter from there or query an item by its ID if you know it beforehand.

For both of these options, you'll need to include the `itemListData=image` parameter.

Example: https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/static-data/v3/items?itemListData=image&api_key=YOUR_RIOT_API_KEY

I'd also suggest caching/storing the items object after the first request for faster access and rate limit efficiency.

If you use NodeJS, [take a look at this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lol-item-image) ([the source is available here](https://github.com/Vitaefinis/lol-item-image)).

Note that if you use the package above, your first request will go to the Riot Games API and the rest will be served from cache, that is until you restart your server. You may wanna implement permanent storage if you would like to frequently restart your server.

Comment: Did you only write this for me?

Comment: I wrote it after I saw your question, I think there's a legitimate need. I plan on expanding this for all the image related endpoints in the Static Data API.

Comment: Thanks that's really great! I wrote a little bravery programm for my stream, this is the reason why I needed it

Comment: Hi Alican, Do you know what it has changed to with the update to the v4 endpoints? This is not working for me currently:

```import urllib.request
API_KEY = 'RGAPI-'

imgs = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/static-data/v3/items?itemListData=image&api_key={}".format(API_KEY)

contents = urllib.request.urlopen(imgs).read()```